# Typing animation in CSS going beyond specified limit

Tags: html, css

The typing animation is stopping at a set character number every time. If I extend the statement, it cuts off. If I shorten the statement, it keeps going until it hits the set character number. I understand I have to change the number of steps (50), but that is not really the true number it stops at, it stops at 28.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@200&display=swap');
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 75%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50);
}

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 5s steps(50) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 750ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 16em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: rgb(155, 211, 71);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line anim-typewriter">Under construction...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust where the keyframes will end by reducing the width paramater here:

```
@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 16em;
  }
}
```

Change the width to 13em and the cursor will blink at the end of your string:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@200&display=swap');
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 75%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50);
}

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 5s steps(50) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 750ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 13em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: rgb(155, 211, 71);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line anim-typewriter">Under construction...</p>
```

This is the easiest way but in the future if you have dynamic sized strings you'd want to update the width based on string length (number of characters).